MyPy displays an error when inheriting from str and adding metaclass
Here's simple example of code:
class meta(type): pass
class Test(str, metaclass = meta): pass

When I run mypy on it (just from cli, without any flags or other additional setup) I'm seeing next output:
test.py:2: error: Metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases  [misc]

I know that similar error appears at runtime when metaclass of derived class is not a subtype of all parents metaclasses. But type(str) is type, and my class meta derived from type, so I cannot understand what's incorrect here.
Provided example isn't working only with str parent class. Mypy says everything is correct when inheriting from int or float.
So, how to get rid of such error message? Or it is just a mypy bug?

There is no way "static type checking" can ever mach runtime language capabilities. This is a mypy problem - which they may or may not try to workaround to match the runtime behavior in the comming years. I would not wait for that. The problem being MyPy will see the virtual subclassing added to str for ends of type-checking as a "real" subclass.

Sadly no answer in mypy metaclasses docs: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/metaclasses.html

str is statically-typed as a subclass of typing.Protocol, whose metaclass is special-cased by mypy as typing._ProtocolMeta (typing.Protocol is actually an instance of typing._ProtocolMeta at runtime, but this isn't reflected in the typing stubs, so normally mypy wouldn't know about this).
Therefore, to accurately reflect both static typing and runtime in your example, you can do this (mypy Playground, Pyright Playground):
import typing as t

if t.TYPE_CHECKING:
    from typing import _ProtocolMeta
else:
    _ProtocolMeta = type(str)

class meta(_ProtocolMeta): pass
class Test(str, metaclass=meta): pass

Since typing._ProtocolMeta has a bare minimum typing interface, this leaves you relatively free to implement meta without too much maintenance if type-checkers and/or the Python runtime decides to change the metaclass of str in the future.
Note that keyword arguments in a class declaration do not currently work properly in mypy for user-defined metaclasses, so you'll run into some type-safety issues for those. Instead of using metaclasses, consider using a base class defining __init_subclass__ instead.

Interesting, but _ProtocolMeta is private so this is not the perfect solution we would like to see

@NoamNol indeed, but since usage of it is confined to TYPE_CHECKING, you’ll never get runtime issues even if the implementation details change or the symbol stopped existing altogether. As long as your CI process (with static typing) catches any changes, fixes should be a one-liner.

It would be nice to just write class meta(type(str)): pass but mypy rejects it with Unsupported dynamic base class "type"

I think this is because str inherits from Sequence[str], which itself inherits from the type-checking time Protocol of type _SpecialForm:
# builtins.pyi
class str(Sequence[str]): ...

# typing.pyi
Protocol: _SpecialForm

class Collection(Iterable[_T_co], Container[_T_co], Protocol[_T_co]): ...

class Sequence(Collection[_T_co], Reversible[_T_co]): ...

I'm not sure if Mypy is right or wrong here (if this is implementation-dependent, neither is also possible).
It should be noted that it also raises other errors of the same kind for bytes, Enum and ABC but not for Fraction, which inherits from Rational, a Protocol:
# numbers.pyi
class _RealLike(_ComplexLike, Protocol): ...

class Real(Complex, _RealLike): ...

class Rational(Real): ...

# fractions.pyi
class Fraction(Rational): ...

For comparison, Pyright says that str and bytes are fine but Fraction is not; it agrees with Mypy on Enum and ABC.

str does not "inherit" from Sequence[str] - it inherits from type - it is registered as a virtual subclass of Sequence[str]. The threshold to know if it is a Mypy bug or if it is correct is simple: if it is a real runtime error, then it is incorrect. If it works as intended, and mypy flags it as an error (the case in question), then it is a mypy bug.

@jsbueno you can't test it like this. many things can be wrong from the typing perspective but still run without errors

@jsbueno At runtime str is a C thing and registered as a virtual subclass of Sequence[str], sure, but at type checking time "virtual subclass" (or even "class") is not a thing; as defined, str is a symbol in the type system, a type that implements/inherits Sequence[str]. Also, your threshold is rather unrealistic. The static type system do not need to agree with its runtime counterpart.

"The static type system do not need to agree with its runtime counterpart" yes. so, when it errors, and the program is correct, one should ignore it, not spend time finding workarounds for the typing system understand what you want to do (or rather, what you are already doing).
